# "Object required" error on getElementById

Tags: excel, vba, getelementbyid

When I attempt getElementById, a run-time error 424 is thrown.

Basically, my code opens and logs into a web page, then clicks a button to navigate to a new screen.  Once this new screen loads, we try to click the aforementioned button that throws an error.

```
Sub Website()

    Dim ie_Obj As InternetExplorer

    Set ie_Obj = New InternetExplorer
    ie_Obj.Visible = True

    ie_Obj.navigate "https://www.websitehere.omitted/"
    Do While ie_Obj.Busy = True Or ie_Obj.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ie_Obj.Document.getElementById("LoginBtn").Click ' This one works fine.  What's wrong with the next one?
    Do While ie_Obj.Busy = True Or ie_Obj.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' I added this to allow the page to load.

    ie_Obj.Document.getElementById("chkAllrlbLocs").Click' <--- Code breaks here

    '... more code follows
```

I am aware that one of the reasons could be because the page has not finished loading; however, if I go line-by-line with F8 and allow it to load, it will still throw the error.

This is my HTML:

```
<input name="chkAllrlbLocs" tabindex="-1" id="chkAllrlbLocs" onclick="if (! SelectAllLBItems('rlbLocs')) return false;setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'chkAllrlbLocs\',\'\')', 0)" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: What is the object you're trying to interact with, is it a checkbox?

Comment: Have you deliberately removed the login lines? Can you check you target element is not inside a parent frame/iframe element?

Answer (score 0):

"chkAllrlbLocs" is no Id, it's a name. But "name" is only an attribute. So try this:
(If it wont work, you should post the url)

```
    Sub Website()

    Dim ie_Obj As InternetExplorer
    Dim inputTags As Object

    Set ie_Obj = New InternetExplorer
    ie_Obj.Visible = True

    ie_Obj.navigate "https://www.websitehere.omitted/"
    Do While ie_Obj.Busy = True Or ie_Obj.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ie_Obj.Document.getElementById("LoginBtn").Click ' This one works fine.  What's wrong with the next one?
    'The following line doesn't work because "ie_Obj.Busy = True Or ie_Obj.readyState <> 4: DoEvents" is
    'already at "ready" . You are saved by the following line after this: "Application.Wait ..."
    'So I commented it out
    'Do While ie_Obj.Busy = True Or ie_Obj.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' I added this to allow the page to load.

    'This is the "try this" part
    'But I think you must think a little by yourself
    For Each inputTags In ie_Obj.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If inputTags.getAttribute("name") = "chkAllrlbLocs" Then
        'Think about the following comment line
        'Code when the right input field was be found
        Exit For
      End If
    Next inputTags

    '... more code follows
End Sub
```

Comment: Ups, @QHarr. You are right I wasn't looking closely, sorry but merry Christmas on this occasion